# Scheduling stream on NSRunLoop

Tags: ios, sockets, nsrunloop, nsinputstream, nsoutputstream

I have been following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server and I got everything working ok, but there is one line in text that I don't understand:

> Our streams have to continuously be ready to send or receive data. To enable this we
>   have to schedule the stream to receive events in a run loop. If we do not assign a run loop
>   the delegate will block the execution of our code until there is no data on the stream to read or write, which is a case we want to avoid.

But, if I comment the lines in code:

```
//[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
//[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

everything will still work fine. I don't really understand why I have to schedule this on main run loop?

As I see it everything that happens on main thread is being handled on this run loop. So if I press button it will be handled on main run loop. Here if I don't schedule this on  main run loop, bytes are still getting received and sent, so to me that means they are procesed on main run loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule your stream in any runloop you want. Delegate's callback methods will be called in a such thread where it was scheduled. For example I wrote some unit tests for my POSInputStreamLibrary where my delegate receives events in a some worker thread. You can see scheduling process [here](https://github.com/pavelosipov/POSInputStreamLibrary/blob/master/POSInputStreamLibraryTests/Helpers/POSRunLoopRunner.m)